# Problem on Symmetric Groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, symmetric-groups

> Prove that a cycle of length $L = k · m$, taken to the $k^{\text{th}}$ power, will decompose into $k$ cycles, each of length $m$.

I have no idea on this one. Kindly help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is sufficient to do this for $\sigma=(1\ 2\ 3\ \cdots\ km)$. Can you compute $\sigma^k$ in cycle notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take the cycle $\sigma=(1,2,...,mk)$. Then 
$$\sigma(a)=a+1$$ 
$$\sigma^2(a)=a+2$$
...
$$\sigma^k(a)=a+k$$
(all done modulo $km$).
Thus,
$$\sigma^k=(1,k+1,...,(m-1)k+1)(2,k+2,...(m-1)k+2)...(k-1,2k-1,...,mk-1)$$

and those are $k$ cycles of length $m$.

Comment: What do you mean by "all done modulo $km$"?

Comment: @Henry It means that whenever the number exceeds $km$, I substract $km$ from it, e.g. $\sigma^7(km-2)=5$ (subtracting $km$ from $km+5$).